# Is there a way to restrict fields in an aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to restrict fields in `aggregate` queries in MongoDB?

With a `find()` you can set fields you don't want to `0` restrict everything but, and with `update`s you and use the `$unset` command (which isn't really the same, but close), but it doesn't seem like there's a way to do it with the `aggregate` command.

When I try to set to `0`, I get:

> "errmsg" : "exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion"

To rephrase this, based on the example from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/, I would like to return all fields in the documents **except** certain fields. Example:

```
db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' }, { type:0 } )
```

It seems with the `aggregate` command that I can only tell it what to *include*, not what to **exclude**

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can show us the aggregate query, sample documents and the expected output.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage in your pipeline to specify the fields to include in your output:

```
{$project: {a: 1, b: 1, _id: 0}}
```

**Update for question update:**

Unfortunately, field exclusion is only supported for `_id` so you can't directly exclude `type` and instead have to include all the fields that you do want.

Comment: you can also display the _id with different name eg. {_id:0, PageId: "$_id"}

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know what all of the fields are. Each document is slightly different, but there are certain fields I don't want to return, say SSN or such.  It seems odd that you can do this with nearly every command in the db, but for aggregate they cripple the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, if your projection stage only consists in discarding fields, you can use `$project`'s alias [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/index.html#pipe._S_unset):

```
// { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
// { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }
db.collection.aggregate({ $unset: ["_id", "b"] })
// { a: 1, c: 3 }
// { a: 4, c: 6 }
```

where `["_id", "b"]` is the list of fields to discard.